# Program to produce the following pattern

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to print

```
2
1 3
2 4 6
1 3 5 7
2 4 6 8 10
```

I am not sure how to do it ,I could use print (...) And write everything but that is just stupid.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Make two loops. One for the rows, and the second for printing the numbers. Make sure that you only print the even numbers when you are on odd rows, and vice versa.

Comment: Using print function is correct... What issues are you having?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

maybe you can try this:

```
>>> def pattern_gen(layer):
...     for i in range(layer):
...         pattern=''
...         start=(i+1)%2+1
...         end=(i+(i+1)%2+1)*2
...         for j in range(start,end,2):
...             pattern+=f'{j} '
...         print(pattern)
...
>>> pattern_gen(5)
2
1 3
2 4 6
1 3 5 7
2 4 6 8 10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(0, 5):
  for j in range(0, i+1):
    if i % 2 == 0:
      print((j+1)*2, end=' ')
    else:
      print((j*2)+1, end=' ')
  print()
```